# How do I find the Sub derivative of this function?

Tags: derivatives

I have a simple equation where I need to find the subderivative and then df(0), df(1) etc.

The equation is given by:
[image]

Can someone explain how to find this?

Comment: Do you need the full sub derivative (a set) or just a sub derivative (an element of that set)?

Comment: what is the "sub derivative"???

Comment: @JensRenders I guess both?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Not sure, its what was referred to in the book